# asp.net core 6 The configuration file 'appsettings.json' was not found and is not optional

Tags: c#

[The code where I specify the path to the appsettings.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qj3BN.png):

[image: This pic is my error message]

Even though I specified the path to the appsettings file, it gives an error while creating migrations.
Even if I always select the appsetting.json properties as copy always, it didn't fix it.

[image]

Comment: To increase the quality of the question, please copy the code instead of the image, and put your errors in the bracket. Thank you.

Comment: Well, are you sure the file is in the path displayed in the Output window ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was fixed when I deleted the code on line 10.
new code blog:

```
 static public class Configuration
{
    static public string ConnectionString
    {
        get
        {
            ConfigurationManager configurationManager = new();
            //configurationManager.SetBasePath(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),"../"));
            configurationManager.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");


            return configurationManager.GetConnectionString("MsSqlServer");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should replace the line number 10 for this line of code:

```
configurationManager.SetBasePath(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location))
```

Comment: didn't happen. New error message: The expected physical path was 'C:\Users\Emre\.dotnet\tools\.store\dotnet-ef\6.0.3\dotnet-ef\6.0.3\tools\netcoreapp3.1\any\tools\netcoreapp2.0\any\appsettings.json'.